# How to pass a child class as a parameter instead of the parent?

Tags: c#

I found myself working with a library that defines three clases. The class `Element` and the class `ElementFile : Element` which is a child class of the first one, and a third class called `Message`.

I have been copying some functionalities from an other program that has been given to me as an example on how to use the previously mentioned library. This program is written in VisualBasic but we are currently working with C# so I ended up finding a part of the code I don't know how to adapt.

In VisualBasic they are doing this:

```
Dim message As Message = library.NewMessage
Dim elem As New ElementFile("path")
message.addElement(elem)
```

And with my lack of knowledge I tried to reproduce it like this in C#:

```
Message message = library.NewMessage();
ElementFile elem = new ElementFile("path");
message.addElement(ref elem);
```

The problem is that the method `addElement` expects the first parameter to be of `Element` type.
I used JustDecompile to check the declaration of this method in the library and it looks like this:

```
public class Message
{
    public void addElement(ref Element elem){ ... }
}
```

Why is `addMethod` accepting an `ElementFile` variable as parameter in VisualBasic and how to do the same in C#? Can someone confirm me please if the VisualBasic code makes any sense?

Comment: You should be able to pass a more-derived class (ElementFile) to a method expecting an Element without issue. Does it give you an error?

Comment: @itsme86 It's a `ref` parameter.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Oops, yup. Just noticed that.

Comment: @Grirg If you declare `elem` as `Element` rather than as `ElementFile`, it'll compile. I'm curious as to why the VB version compiles (bc I don't know VB).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Option Strict Off maybe? Or just because there is no `ref` keyword?

Comment: @AFriend Isn't VB `ByRef` equivalent to C# `ref`?

Comment: Why is the parameter a `ref` parameter anyways? Does the code in `addElement` change the object that `elem` is referencing? If not, then take `ref` off.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to fix `addElement` so that it takes an `Element`, not a `ref Element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declared type of `elem` to `Element`, and the C# code will compile:

```
Element elem = new ElementFile("path");
message.addElement(ref elem);
```

[And here's why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/): `ref Element e` means "`e` must be a thing **to which** you may assign an instance of `Element`". A reference to `ElementFile` does not meet that requirement.

The method *could* be doing this:

```
public void Test(ref Element e)
{
    e = new Element();
}
```

That's fine if the referenced reference back in the caller is of type `Element`. 
It's not at all fine if we were given a ref to a reference of a derived type such as `ElementFile`. Then we'd be effectively doing this:

```
ElementFile e = new ElementFile();

//  Nope. 
e = new Element();
```

If we just add a constraint saying the method can't assign to it, then it's not `ref` any more: You implement exactly that in your method by omitting the `ref` keyword.

So the compiler won't let you do that with `ref`.

This is essentially the same reason why you can't cast `IList<ElementFile>` to `IList<Element>`, but you *can* cast `IEnumerable<ElementFile>` to `IEnumerable<Element>`.

As for the reason why the VB code works, [see Hans Passant's excellent answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16855358/424129). VB has an explicit special case for this.

Comment: Thank you for such a well argumented and structured answer with references to similar cases. Very instructive, so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you do this (note the variable type change for `elem`):

```
Message message = library.NewMessage();
Element elem = new ElementFile("path");
message.addElement(ref elem);
```